# AutoHotKey KeyWait selects everything?

Tags: autohotkey

So i have made this script whenever I click it types 3, then 4, then 3 and so on and so on. But my problem is that when I click too fast, or sometimes just at random, it selects everything and then deletes it. Any idea why?

```
a = 3

loop {
reset:
a = 3
goto start
start:

if (a = 3) {
KeyWait, LButton, D
KeyWait, LButton
sleep 50
send, 4
a = 4
goto, start
}

else {
KeyWait, LButton, D
KeyWait, LButton
sleep 50
send, 3
a = 3
goto, start
}
F11::
Pause
goto, reset
}



!z::ExitApp
```

Comment: Double clicking usually highlights a word or line. So if you double-click, you are going to highlight a bunch of text, then replace it with `3`.

Comment: That might actually be that.. Now I feel kinda dumb haha, thanks anyways.